# Selenium invalid XPath error

Tags: java, xml, selenium, xpath

I get the following error:

```
com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Invalid xpath [2]: //input[@value='Accedi']
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:112)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand(HttpCommandProcessor.java:106)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.click(DefaultSelenium.java:193)
```

The XML part of the file is:

```
<p>
<div><input class="login button" type="submit" value="Accedi" /></div>
</p>
```

My Java code is:

```
selenium.click("//input[@value='Accedi']");
```

I have tried to change single quotes into double quotes, changed xpath to:

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/form/p[4]/div/input[@value="Accedi"]
```

Which I got from a tool.

Why are all the XPaths that I have tried wrong?

Comment: Are you waiting after opening the page? Could be that the element is not there yet when you try to click it.

Comment: Nothing looks wrong with the xpath. Possibly related to [Issue 6055](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6055); Is this behavior across all browsers or a specific browser/version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you make sure few things:

- Can you make sure the Xpath evaluation is returning just a single object which you want to click.
- If you are able to identify your object uniquely, then can you try clicking using below suggestions?
- Can you try this Xpath : //input[contains(@class,'login button')] or
  //input[contains(@value,'Accedi')]
- If you still facing the issue, can you please post the Selenium
  Version and the browser you are using. If you are using chrome or IE,
  also specify the driver version for the same.

Comment: The reason was that my Firefox driver version was not corresponding to the Firefox that I had installed.